# Help needed in understanding the answer to a simple question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In one of the problem the statement is as follows:

Without computing $\mathbb{A}$, find the basis for its four fundamental subspaces: $$
\mathbb{A}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    6 & 1 & 0\\
    9 & 8 & 1
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}
$$ I understand the other parts of the solution but I do not know how the column space basis are $(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)$? Should they not be $(1,6,9),(0,1,8),(0,0,1)$ because the pivot columns of second matrix are the first three columns. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\operatorname{Span}\{(1,0,0)^T, (0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\}=\mathbb{R}^3=\operatorname{Span}\{(1,6,9)^T,(0,1,8)^T,(0,0,1)^T\}$$

Hence, your answer is correct as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Would not this means that if we know the dimension of the column subspace then just use the columns of the identity matrix and they will be the column space basis of that matrix? Because, I think, this is what happened here.

Comment: hmm...when it is equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$, things are easy. In general, we might not be able to choose columns of the identity matrix. $dim(\operatorname{Span}\{(1,1)^T\})=1$ but $\operatorname{Span}\{(1,1)^T\} \ne\operatorname{Span}\{(1,0)^T\}  $

Comment: Thank you for clarifying with an easy to understand example.